# Cannot open second Modal (or only opens modal-backdrop) after closing Modal (Bootstrap Modal with Google map) using Angular, JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATED**

I need some fresh eyes on my problem. I have done a lot of research and have tried everything I can think of, but for some reason I simply cannot get my modals to behave in the way I want them to.

**My issue:**

After opening modal one (which has a Google map and Google auto complete address field), I trigger via a button click the close of modal one, and opening modal two. But modal two does not open, or you only see the `modal-backdrop`.

**My code:**

(1) The first modal is opened via this click event:

```
<a class="shop-btn" id="5G router-32" (click)="startFivegJourney()">buy</a>
```

(2) The click event fires this method which opens the `#five-g-product-modal`. The reason for the additional `shown.bs.modal` code is simply for setting the `z-index` of the modal, making sure that the Google autocomplete address field does not display behind the opened modal.

```
startFivegJourney() {
    if (this.cartService.simsInCart.length > 0) {
      $('#modal-clear-cart').modal('show');
    } else {
      $('#five-g-product-modal').modal('show');
      $('#five-g-product-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', () => {
        $('.pac-container').css('z-index', $('#five-g-product-modal').css('z-index'));
      });
    }
}
```

(3) A button click event fired from modal one that is now open, triggers the method below, which hides modal one.

```
checkFiveGCoverage() {
    $('#five-g-product-modal').modal('hide');

    $('#five-g-product-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
      $('#five-g-coverage-modal').modal('show');
      this.openModal();
    });
}
```

(4) After modal one has completely closed, a simple method is called to open the new modal:

```
openModal() {
    $('#five-g-coverage-modal').modal('show');
}
```

I have tried various ways of opening the modal (the modal does open on top of the first modal if I do not close the first modal), but it is as if it does not fire, or opens the `modal-backdrop` only. Thank you in advance!

Comment: in this syntax $('five-g-coverage-modal').modal('show'); selector seems wrong. you need use either id or class selector

Comment: I would highly recommend against using *any* jQuery with angular.  ngx-bootstrap is definitely the way to go.

Comment: stop using Angular if you can help it. Way too complicated for 99.9% of use-cases. Use Vue.js, much friendlier and easier to use. And as far as the Bootstrap modal, it's a wrapper around the "dialog" html element (might have the name wrong, but there's an HTML 5 element that IS the dialog box). Just write your own CSS hoss.

Comment: @Robert Apologies, forgot the # for the IDs. I have updated the code.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Why would you advice against using jQuery with Angular?